# Bootstrap 3 TypeAhead source from function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

**Tl;DR** [Here is the process](http://jsfiddle.net/28ZFH/1/) I'm trying to get to work. Note the source for the array is pulled from an `ajax` method.

I'm trying to upgrade our systems from a much previous version of <kbd>TypeAhead</kbd> to the latest.

I currently have a function that takes in three parameters, and returns a `{value: 'value'}` string array.

All I need to do is hook up <kbd>TypeAhead</kbd> to that function as a data source. I've tried to use all types of modified methods from [their examples page](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote), and [their documentation page](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md).

I've burnt through all the examples to the following:

```
$("#control").typeahead({
    source: function(query, callback) {
        typeaheadResults(query, "case", null);
    }
});
```

I need the typeahead to update as the user changes text (<kbd>Bloodhound engine</kbd> likes to prefetch all the results then filter through that - Something I can't do)

**Edit**
The origionall source lead me down this path

```
    var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;

            // an array that will be populated with substring matches
            matches = [];

            // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

            // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
            // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
            $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                    // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                    matches.push({ value: str });
                }
            });

            cb(matches);
        };
    };

    var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
      'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
      'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
      'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
      'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
      'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
      'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
      'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
      'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
    ];

    $("#control").typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'states',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: substringMatcher(states)
    });
```

However, that's the prefetched list I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Just visually appealing, and easier to pick up the elements

Comment: does `typeaheadResults` return an array?

Comment: Yes, it returns a `{value: 'value'}` string array.